# MySQL Query to Update a Field with data from another Field when two Fields Match

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I need to update the content of one data field in a table with the content of another field in a table every time two separate fields, one on each table, match up. I've been trying this syntax but I just can't get it to work properly without giving me an error.

```
UPDATE table1
   SET field1 = table2.field1
  FROM Table1,Table2
 WHERE Table1.entry = Table2.entry
```

Comment: The FROM clause should contain table names, not field names.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that each `field2.entry` has exactly one possible `table2.field1`?

Comment: FROM Table1,Table2 is the correct one, typo on my part, and no each field2.entry usually has only one corresponding field1 value but it may have more, in which case I don't really care which value it copies over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`update ... from` is sql server's syntax.  In MySQL you can just use multiple tables directly:

```
update
  table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.field = t1.field
set
  t1.field1 = t2.matchingfield
where
  t1.whatever = t2.whatever
```

All is detailed on the MySQL update [reference page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/update.html).